# Hibernate: Need help getting Java Property variables to work

Tags: java, hibernate, properties

I have a Class with variables that use Java Properties. When I try to run a simple Query, I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Exception occurred inside setter of persons.Person.active

...

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

...

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at persons.Person.setActive
```

It's something wrong with the setter of the active variable, but I don't see anything wrong.

Here's the code I'm using

```
private BooleanProperty active;

@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public boolean isActive() {
    return activeProperty().get();
}

public BooleanProperty activeProperty() {
    return active ;
}

public void setActive(boolean active) {
    activeProperty().set(active);
}
```

If anyone could help, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you initializing BooleanProperty active?

Comment: lol I'm not (I feel silly). I'll try adding code for initializing the BooleanProperty in the default Constructor and get back to you.

Comment: I think that should be the root cause of null pointer exception